# Remotely Launch Nodes in ROS2

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to remotely launch nodes in ROS2? This could be done in ROS1 using the `<machine>` attribute. It's listed in the [ROS2 design document](https://design.ros2.org/articles/roslaunch.html#launching-nodes-processes-remotely-and-portability) but I can't figure out how to use it. I'm using the python `launch` and `launch_ros` libraries.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364152/remotely-launch-nodes-in-ros2/) by [smorad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61624/smorad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2020-10-26

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [resnault](https://answers.ros.org/users/72776/resnault/) on 2021-04-01**:
Hi. Same need. I didn't find into the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I can tell, this is still a work in progress, but has been on the backlog to get merged into the documentation. Lots of discussion [here](https://github.com/ros2/design/pull/297), and it seems the change to the documentation is awaiting approval to get merged in.

The *tentative* document can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/design/blob/acb998756be1bdae5ce816794335e3950e3a3ed2/articles/153_roslaunch_remote_launch.md), but it doesn't look like the proposed changes have made their way into code yet.

I'd imagine it is pretty low priority because ssh is possible on all the tier 1 platforms (ever since Windows joined the club).

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alikureishy](https://answers.ros.org/users/54063/alikureishy/) on 2022-02-17**:
It has been quite some time since this was posted. Could anyone comment on when support for remote-launching nodes via roslaunch can be expected to make it into ROS2?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just found a way to perform a remote launch from a python launch file using the ExecuteProcess launch action. There are several problems you're going to face if you go this way, so here are the workarounds I used to solve them (on Ubuntu 20.04).

First, let's state what we are trying to achieve:

1. We have a main **machine A** and a **machine B** reachable via `ssh pi@192.168.0.20` from **machine A** (without a password, i.e. use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 && ssh-copy-id pi@192.168.0.20` first)
2. We have a launch file `drinks_hmi_launch.py` in `drinks_hmi_bringup` package on **machine B** (we can launch it from machine B via `ros2 launch drinks_hmi_bringup drinks_hmi_launch.py`)
3. We have a launch file `drinks_bringup_launch.py` in `drinks_bringup` package on **machine A** which is supposed (among other actions) to launch `drinks_hmi_launch.py` on **machine B**

Now the following command should work from **machine A**, i.e. it launches the nodes, prints out output and can be terminated via SIGINT (Ctrl+C):

```
ssh -t pi@192.168.0.20 'bash -i -c "ros2 launch drinks_hmi_bringup drinks_hmi_launch.py"'
```

However, after putting it directly into `ExecuteProcess` action in `drinks_bringup_launch.py`, the process complains about not having a proper `tty` console and the nodes on **machine B** are not terminated after terminating the `ros2 launch drinks_bringup drinks_bringup_launch.py` process.

A workaround is to call the above command inside a detached `screen` (use `sudo apt install screen` if not present). This, however, raises two further problems:

- The `screen` does not pass SIGINT from calling process to inner processes, so it does not terminate the nodes when Ctrl+C is pressed. However it can be terminated explicitly using a `remote_launch_terminator` node which calls `screen -S hmi -X quit` (see the complete solution below)
- The `screen` does not pass output from inner processes to calling process, so this needs to be done explicitly by redirecting inner output to [outer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40270593/4003774)

**The complete solution is as follows:**

`/home/machine_A/drink_ws/src/launch_utils/launch_utils/remote_launch_terminator.py`:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import os

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    node = Node('remote_launch_terminator')
    node.declare_parameter('screen_pid', 'remote')
    screen_pid = node.get_parameter('screen_pid').get_parameter_value().string_value

    try:
        rclpy.spin(node)
    except:
        pass

    print('Terminating ' + screen_pid)
    os.system('screen -S ' + screen_pid + ' -X quit')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`/home/machine_A/drink_ws/src/drinks_bringup/launch/drinks_bringup_launch.py`:

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions.execute_process import ExecuteProcess

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        
        # other actions
        
        # remote launch
        ExecuteProcess(
            name='hmi',
            cmd=['{ outer_stdout=$(readlink -f /proc/self/fd/3); } 3>&1 && screen -DmS hmi bash -i -c "ssh -t pi@192.168.0.20 \'bash -i -c \\"ros2 launch drinks_hmi_bringup drinks_hmi_launch.py\\"\' > $outer_stdout"'],
            output="screen",
            shell=True,
            emulate_tty=True
        ),
        Node(
            package='launch_utils',
            executable='remote_launch_terminator',
            name='remote_launch_terminator',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'screen_pid': 'hmi'}]
        ),
    ])
```

Hope this helps, cheers! ;)

Note: `ExecuteProcess` action does not work inside `OnShutdown` event, that's why the `remote_launch_terminator` must be used

---

Originally posted by [afrixs](https://answers.ros.org/users/37597/afrixs/) with karma: 61 on 2022-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My answer to this is to use the existing linux system to do this: **systemd**. Basically do the following:

On the target machine, the machine you want to run remote nodes on, do the following:

1. Make sure the nodes you want to run are on the remote machine already and it's already built on that machine.
2. Make a bash script that executes ros2 launch and sources the right install directory. We'll call this remote_ros.sh. This is a script because you might want to do other things with this.
3. Make a remote_ros.service file that runs the remote_ros.sh script. This can be setup to start on boot or not.

On the local machine, the machine you want to launch remote nodes on, do the following:

1. Make a launch script that SSHes into the remote machine and executes `systemctl stop remote_ros` and/or `systemctl start remote_ros`. This can be done with the ExecuteProcess launch action.

Stop will kill the nodes and start will bring them up. If you don't want to stop the nodes, I believe start is a NOOP if they are already running.

I think this solution is more straight forward than the others presented and ideally the service just runs all the time, but you can always kill it with the systemctl stop command.

---

Originally posted by [gerok](https://answers.ros.org/users/118336/gerok/) with karma: 11 on 2022-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1